# ImageView onClickListener() not working

Tags: android, android-imageview

ImageView onclicklistener does not working for the following code. It shows `nullPointerException` in `setOnClickListener`.

```
    ImageView cus_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.cust_list);
    cus_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
        public void onClick(final View v) 
          {
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Customer.class);
              startActivity(myIntent); 
        } 

    });
```

**Error log.**

```
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.First.namespace/com.tiara.tallyApp.New_grid_activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at com.tiara.tallyApp.New_grid_activity.onCreate(New_grid_activity.java:24)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
                    10-16 13:15:40.167: E/AndroidRuntime(568):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: your imageview initialization fails hence you have NPE. `cus_image` is null

Comment: @GrIsHu whats wrong with `v.getContext()`

Comment: He can't pass "this" because it will refer to OnClickListener class.

Comment: please post your layout xml which contain this imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should solve the problem

```
ImageView cus_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cust_list);
cus_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
public void onClick(final View v) 
  {
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Customer.class);
      startActivity(myIntent); 
  } 
});
```

change R.drawable with R.id

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
ImageView cus_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.cust_list);
```

with

```
ImageView cus_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cust_list_img_id); // cust_list_img_id will be id of that imageview in xml file.
```

Answer (score 1):

What fails is:

```
ImageView cus_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.cust_list);
```

Just by looking at the name, "cust_list" and also a "drawable" instead of "id"?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the reference of your imageview from the `drawable` besides you should get the imageview id as `R.id.yourimageviewId`.

Try out as below:

```
  ImageView cus_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.<youriamgeid>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Like This

```
ImageView cus_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cust_list);
cus_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
    public void onClick(final View v) 
      {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(getContext(), Customer.class);
          startActivity(myIntent); 
    } 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You getting error at :

```
ImageView cus_image = (ImageView) findViewById(**R.drawable.cust_list**);
```

replace it with below content:

```
ImageView cus_image = (ImageView) findViewById(**R.id.imageid**);
```

Comment: please post your layout xml which contain this imageview

Answer (score 1):

For sure, please change the way you get your image doing this:

```
ImageView cus_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cust_list_img_id);
```

You have to reference it using the id you have set in your layout and not the drawable to be displayed.

Answer (score -1):

it's showing null pointer exception because Imageview isn't getting his id which you have define like

```
ImageView cus_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.cust_list);
```

it should be:

```
ImageView cus_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cust_list);
```